# Achieve the results of two individual queries using a JOIN

Tags: php, sql

I have a USER table structure as shown below:

```
id  parent_id      userName
10     01        Project manager
11     10        manager
12     11        teamlead
13     12        team member
```

I need to find the project manager ID if I give the team member ID in where clause. I can get the results in each individual query.

But I'm trying to implement it with a JOIN query. I'm new to JOIN queries. How do I do it?

Comment: You could use a `cursor` for that

Comment: what is the name of second table and which fields it has ?

Comment: Please, don't use a cursor for this, a simple join will do

Comment: all the values are in the same table "User".

Comment: What database server are you using (sql server, mysql, oracle, etc)?  **All**, please note that not only is he joining the table with itself, but he's walking a hierarchy..  So, for example, if he's using sql server, he's going to need a CTE

Comment: Actually, please NEVER use a cursor. There are always ways around cursors, even if that concept were needed here. Cursors = bad!

Comment: @saran - Then why do you need to do a `JOIN`?, what is your expected result? (I mean, give us an example of what you want, not just a description)

Comment: I don't want to keep on using the same query to fetch the results from a same table. So i thought of using join query. SELECT id
FROM users JOIN users ON users.id = users.parent_id WHERE id = 13. the error is #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'users'. I'm using mysql

Comment: @saran the problem with your query is you need to use different aliases on users JOIN users ON users.id = users.parent_id so it should be users u1 JOIN users u2 ON u1.id = u2.parent_id. Then you can join on the same table - they just have to have different names

Comment: You have to alias your tables. See my response below. You are right, except you have to put users AS AliasTableName after each from/join. This tells the query which table to use in this recursive join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work with your existing schema

```
SELECT ParentUser.UserName AS ManagerName, BaseUser.UserName AS TeamMemberName 
FROM User AS BaseUser
    INNER JOIN User AS ParentUser
        ON  BaseUser.parent_id = ParentUser.id
WHERE BaseUser.Id = @PassedInTeamMemberId
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks as if this involves a bit more than a simple join.  Be ready to enter a world of pain :).  I recently had a similar problem, but with type hierarchies being stored in a table with a similar structure.  What I ended up with is writing a recursive query.  In Sql Server, you would use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx).  In mysql, you would use loops.

Basically, the idea is that you join a table against itself, walking a hierarchy until you reach the top-level element.  Behind the scenes, the server is creating virtual tables and joining them against each other until some "stopping condition" is reached.  This point is **very important**: be sure that you have your stopping condition correct, or you could cause some serious problems.

[This post](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/) is a great run-down.  Also, a general search for the terms `hierarchical query mysql` in google will result in a wealth of information.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableA.whatever = 'whatever'
```

I find this [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) from the lovely and talented Jeff Atwood to be quite helpful.

Comment: So? This answers the question, If you don't like it write your own answer.